# C#: правильная организация потоков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, task

Добрый день.

У меня есть windows-сервис, который выполняет 5 задач: 4 из них выполняются за 1 минуту, 5ая - за 15 минут. В сервисе есть таймер, который запускает эти задачи на каждую секунду.

Код:

```
class SmsInspectorTasks
{
        DbHelper _dbHelper;
        List<Event> _list;
        LoggerHelper _loggerHelper;
        Settings _settings;
    /*
     * Task1 - Работа с балансами
     * Task2 - Работа с статусами
     * Task3 - Проверка на неотправленые сообщения
     * Task4 - Отправка ежемесячных затрат по Клиентам
     * Task5 - Обработка массовой рассылки
     */

    public SmsInspectorTasks(Settings settings, LoggerHelper loggerHelper)
    {
        _dbHelper = new DbHelper(settings.DBConnection, settings.LogsPath);
        _list = _dbHelper.GetEvents();
        _loggerHelper = loggerHelper;
        _settings = settings;

        _loggerHelper.WriteLog("*** SmsInspectorTasks конструктор", true);
    }


    #region Работа с балансами

    Task Balances()
    {
        Task T = new Task(GetBalances);
        T.Start();

        return T;
    }

    void GetBalances()
    {
      ///....
    }

    #endregion

    #region Работа с статусами

    Task Statuses()
    {
        Task T = new Task(GetStatuses);
        T.Start();

        return T;
    }

    void GetStatuses()
    {
       //...
    }
    #endregion

    #region Проверка на неотправленые сообщения

    Task NonSendMessages()
    {
        Task T = new Task(GetNonSendMessages);
        T.Start();

        return T;
    }

    void GetNonSendMessages()
    {
        //...
    }

    #endregion

    #region Отправка ежемесячных затрат по Клиентам

    Task ClientCosts()
    {
        Task T = new Task(GetClientCosts);
        T.Start();

        return T;
    }

    void GetClientCosts()
    {
        //...
    }

    #endregion

    #region Обработка массовой рассылки

    Task Bulks()
    {
        Task T = new Task(GetBulks);
        T.Start();

        return T;
    }

    void GetBulks()
    {
        //...
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Запустить все задачи на выполнение
    /// </summary>
    public void StartAll()
    {
        var balanceTask = Balances();
        var statuseTask = Statuses();
        var nonSendMsgTask = NonSendMessages();
        var costs = ClientCosts();
        var bulks = Bulks();

    }

}
```

Грубо говоря, есть 5 объектов Task.

Вот что не получается - после того как отработала процедура № 5 за свои 15 минут, **сервис просто висит и ничего не делает.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы сервис нормально работал каждую секунду, а задача № 5 выполнялась себе спокойно 15 минут (она вызывает 1 раз в месяц !!!)

Я так понимаю, нельзя сделать Task.WaitAll() т.к. сервис тогда будет простаивать 15 минут.

**Я думаю сделать через новый таймер (15 мин интервал) только для этой задачи.**

Как бы Вы сделали на моем месте?

Спасибо.

**UPD**

Код таймера:

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
```

...

```
     _timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
            _timer.Interval = 1000;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
```

...

```
 private static void _timerDogwatch_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
              SmsInspectorTaskssi = new SmsInspectorTasks();
             si.StartAll();
        }
```

Comment: Слишком много кода, сведите пример к минимуму

Comment: Уберите из примера работу с базой данных, XML и всё такое. Они точно не существенны для данного вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: @LeonardBertone: `DbHelper _dbHelper` всё ещё там :)

Comment: Покажите код таймера.

Comment: Добавил код таймера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, наверное, забыли выставить свойство `AutoReset` для таймера - вот он и срабатывает всего 1 раз.

---

Совет: создайте по отдельному таймеру на каждую задачу - так будет проще всего.

Кстати, если свойству `SynchronizingObject` таймера присвоить `null` - то вам не надо будет создавать новый поток для задачи, таймер создаст его сам. Уйдут бесполезные повторяющиеся куски кода.